# Order of Marginal Effects in Ordered Regression Model

Tags: microeconomics, econometrics

I'm looking to validate my understanding of marginal effects on the probability of an ordered probit model. I don't understand how ME is calculated in respect to some alternatives.
For example if I have the following model:
$H_i = x_i\beta + \epsilon_i$
where $H_i$ takes on 3 categorical values like a happiness scale for example: 
$$
H_i = 
\begin{cases}
Happy & \text{if $H_i$ = 3}\\
Indifferent & \text{if $H_i$ = 2}\\
Unhappy & \text{if $H_i$ = 1}
\end{cases}
$$
and my error term is normally distributed N(0,1). The generic formula is:
$\frac{\partial pr(h_i=j)}{\partial X_i} = (F'(a_{j-1}-x'_i\beta)-F'(a_{j}-x'_i\beta)*\beta)$ where $\alpha_i$ refers to the threshold between each category calculated from maximum likelihood estimation.

So the MEs would be:

For the first group $\frac{\partial pr(h_i=1)}{\partial X_i} = (-\phi(a_{1}-x'_i\beta)*\beta)$

For the last group
$\frac{\partial pr(h_i=3)}{\partial X_i} = (\phi(a_{2}-x'_i\beta)-\phi(a_{3}-x'_i\beta)*\beta)$

Is this correct? The first group would only depend on itself since there is no previous group, while the last group will always depend on the second to last group?

Comment: 1) Is your data censored?  I suspect so, along the lines of $H_i < 1 \rightarrow 0$ and $H_i > 3 \rightarrow 3$. 2) The first group actually depends on the "zeroeth" group too.  Even if $\alpha_0 = 0$, you should still have two terms there. Intuitively, the marginal effects should depend on the "overlap" of the probability distributions centered on adjacent values of $H_i$.

Comment: I've not looked into whether ordered categorical variables are treated as censored. To some degree, I guess the categorical variables would be considered censored. In regards to the 'zeroeth' group, I would assume $\alpha_0 = 0$ in which case shouldn't my ME for group 1 be correct?

Comment: No, because the term $F'(\alpha_0 - x'_i\beta)$ with $\alpha_0 = 0$ becomes $F'(-x'_i\beta)$.

Comment: Ordered categorical variables may or may not be censored.  It depends in part on whether it makes the math simpler.  Here, you could allow values of $x'\beta$ to vary between minus and plus infinity, or you could "censor" them by forcing all values below 1 to be 1, and all values above 3 to be 3.